# How to check four consecutive days in list?

Tags: python, date

I want to check if there is four consecutive days in dictionary containing multiple values

```
{
' 0004': ['04/13/2017', '04/15/2017', '04/16/2017', '04/17/2017'], 
' 0003': ['04/11/2017', '04/12/2017', '04/13/2017', '04/18/2017','04/19/2017']
}
```

Key ' 004 ' have no consecutive day while key ' 003' have 4 consecutive days

I am not getting from where I start.Help me out

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please demonstrate your current efforts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014937/3521116 similar question answered here

Comment: @EdChum I am not getting from where I start, can you help me out from this

Comment: check this @wiki http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589523/how-to-detect-if-dates-are-consecutive-in-python similar question